# Google UI controls in websites

Tags: gwt

I am wondering whether Google is using any public API to build user interfaces. For example, if you visit translate.google.com, the DropDown Lists, Tooltips, and Buttons, are these UI controls available for 3rd party websites?

Thanks

Comment: Useful or want more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what Google uses specifically, however, here are some which you can load via the `google.load` Javascript API which will load frameworks and UI frameworks.

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#ext-core

```
 google.load("chrome-frame", "1.0.2");
  google.load("dojo", "1.6.1");
  google.load("ext-core", "3.1.0");
  google.load("jquery", "1.6.2");
  google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
  google.load("mootools", "1.3.2");
  google.load("prototype", "1.7.0.0");
  google.load("scriptaculous", "1.9.0");
  google.load("swfobject", "2.2");
  google.load("yui", "3.3.0");
  google.load("webfont", "1.0.22");
```